# IRS E-File API?

Tags: xml, web-services

I've been trying to understand how IRS e-file works. Does anyone know if it's a public API, and if so, where I can get information on it? Google has not been helpful.

Comment: Hi `Joemoe` I have developed an xml file as per specified in PDF's but I am getting an error on Starting of file as `<ErrorMessage>Line 5: [--MIME94xBoundary] is not a valid MIME header type (must begin with Content- or X-)</ErrorMessage>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this page has the list of documentation for the efile process:
https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/become-an-authorized-e-file-provider

Comment: You don't by chance know how to find an updated link, do you?  This one is now broken.

Comment: Not certain, but it might be the same as: http://www.irs.gov/taxpros/providers/article/0,,id=222533,00.html

Comment: Both links are dead now.

Comment: I was able to find the 2012 link on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20100703152709/http://www.irs.gov/taxpros/providers/article/0,,id=222533,00.html

Comment: If the link falls out of date again, the page title is "Become an Authorized e-file Provider", dropping that in a search engine should work.

Answer (score 11):

My company, http://www.aplossoftware.com is an Authorized IRS e-File Provider.  It is quite the process to get approved to become an e-file provider for the IRS.  Several layers of application, fingerprinting, FBI background checks, to extremely buggy sdk... with few log explanations.

If you are serious about getting into the IRS e-file program, Publication 3112 was a helpful overview of process: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p3112.pdf

IRS recently updated their site and changed all the urls with no forwarding...

Here is the Modernized e-File main page:
https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/modernized-e-file-program-information

Another helpful document is Publication 4164, Modernized e-File Guide for Software Developers and Transmitters.

E-file application questions are handled by the e-Help Desk.
Here is the e-Help desk email inbox:
irs.e-helpmail@irs.gov
You can email that inbox for any specific inquiries.

IRS also does have an SDK. You just have to email the help desk to request it and they'll send you a form to fill out to officially request it.

Good luck..

Comment: What format is the API in? Is it structured data (e.g. JSON, XML) or does it take PDF files? Every efile service seems to generate PDFs, so I had assumed that's what they submitted to the IRS, but perhaps that's incorrect.

Comment: @Nateowami, if you read Publication 4164, Section 2, it says "The IRS uses Extensible Markup Language (XML), the language that specifies the structure and content of an XML document, to implement all forms and schedules in electronic format for Modernized e-file."

Answer (score 0):

Was curious about this and things seem to have changed in the last few years with the [IRS Modernized e-File program](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/modernized-e-file-program-information). The basic answer is the API specification is public, but to actually transmit a tax return you have to go through lots of certifications to prove your identity, readiness, and compliance.

The actual technical mechanism is transmission of XML documents [described here](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/modernized-e-file-mef-user-guides-and-publications), bundled with supplementary XML documents and PDF attachments. These are placed in a ZIP file submitted using a SOAP message. Submissions seem to be signed with an IRS-specific set of SSL certificates.

[The documentation](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/modernized-e-file-mef-user-guides-and-publications) also mentions a limited-access API, presumably to abstract away some of this activity.